# change spacing between items in checkListBox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, itemscontrol, spaces, checklistbox

*I'm using c# visual studio 2010

How can I change the spacing between items in checkListBox componenet.

I see I able to view the spacing by using:

```
checkedListBox1.Margin.Vertical
```

But, how can I change this value?

I would like to mention that I tried also doing as specified in the article cited in the comment below,

but it doesn't work to me

Thanks!

Comment: Is this really windows forms?

Comment: His solution doesn't work to me

Comment: You can increase the vertical distance between items by increasing the `ItemHeight`. `listBox1.ItemHeight = 20;`

Answer (score 0):

Try `checkListBox1.Margin.Padding = new Thickness( left, top, right, bottom );`
Padding is a property, which means you can't edit it in the usual sense, however you can assign it to a new (or existing) instance of a Thickness object.

Comment: I have only checkedListBox1.Margin.Vertical , so I can set to it?

Comment: You can set to any Thickness property. You could also just try setting to checkedListBox1.Margin, do some testing and see what works for you.

Comment: Your first solution doesn't work to me, and I tried also: checkedListBox1.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);  but the compiler don't familiar with Thickness (and I got compliation error about)

Comment: Ah, sorry. It's not `Thickness`, you have to set it with `Padding`. Too used to working on WPF stuff, I guess! Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.margin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: now it passed compilation, but it didn't change the status. I did: checkedListBox1.Margin = new Padding(20,20,20,20);, and it stays as it was before

Comment: You'll have to create a new class that inherits from the control and override the spacing. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8959344/4440992) and see if this answer helps. Define that class and use the new class instead of the old one. It should have the new spacing.

Comment: I copied and paste the solution to my project so it seems that l.ItemHeight = 30 doesn't work.. any ideas?