# How to override ItemHeight Property of CheckedListbox with derived class?

Tags: c#, winforms, derived-class, margins, checkedlistbox

As briefly explained in the title im looking for a way to set the margin between 2 checkboxes and i found the solution for that here: [How to change CheckedListBox item vertical space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959146/how-to-change-checkedlistbox-item-vertical-space) but i dont really get how that works or where i have to put the class to override the property, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it pretty well explained? You put that code:

```
public sealed class  MyListBox:CheckedListBox
{
    public MyListBox()
    {
        ItemHeight = 30;
    }
    public override int ItemHeight { get; set; }
}
```

Into a [new class file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287565(v=vs.71).aspx) and use it in your designer (you may have to clean & rebuild your solution):

[image: Toolbox]

Which then has the desired margin:

[image: margin]