# ItemHeight Property for CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, properties, checkedlistbox

So I'm new to coding and just messing around with Visual C#. I'm trying to space out the items in the CheckedListBox, and I realized there is no ItemHeight Property unlike the ListBox. I've done some searching and came across some similar threads, both on this site and others showing what to do. However, like I said, I'm super new to programming and have no idea how to implement the code suggested by this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959146/how-to-change-checkedlistbox-item-vertical-space).

Can someone guide me on how I to "override a class" or something? In like simpler words and show me where and how I can make the CheckedListBox prettier by spacing the stuff out?

Comment: It doesn't get simpler than the linked post.  Create the class first, rebuild, then put the control on your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here are two examples:**

- one with a fixed item height
- one that fetches item height externally, useful so you can reuse the same control over and over

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public class Example1 : CheckedListBox
    {
        public override int ItemHeight
        {
            get { return 100; }
        }
    }

    public class Example2 : CheckedListBox
    {
        private readonly Func<int> _itemHeight;

        public Example2(Func<int> itemHeight)
        {
            _itemHeight = itemHeight;
        }

        public override int ItemHeight
        {
            get { return _itemHeight(); }
        }
    }

    public class Example2Test
    {
        public Example2Test()
        {
            var example2 = new Example2(GetItemHeight);
        }

        private int GetItemHeight()
        {
            return 100;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

Rebuild your project first, then find your newly created custom control in Toolbox window.

[image]

Comment: Tysm... i think I somewhat understand now.