# How can I change the Item Height in a checklistbox so the item text is not cut-off?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, checklistbox

When I create a checklistbox on a form and populate the y's, g's, etc. get cut-off by the next item.
I've found similar questions answered from years ago ([How to change CheckedListBox item vertical space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959146/how-to-change-checkedlistbox-item-vertical-space)) and tried implementing their fixes but there's not enough details to work it out.

Right now, I go to add -> new item -> class and add a class to my solution. The class looks like this

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test_GUI
{
    public sealed class MyListBox : CheckedListBox
    {
        public MyListBox()
        {
            ItemHeight = 30;
        }
        public override int ItemHeight { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the object appears in my toolbox like
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLttL.png)

but once I drag and drop it to the form it gives me this [image]

If anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong it would be a great help. This has frustrated me to no end. Thanks!

Comment: You have to rebuild the project before attempting to insert any new custom controls. Did you do that?

Comment: Do you also have means to set the Font size to a value compatible with the ItemHeight?

Comment: Rebuild your project for "Any CPU". Restarting VS may also be required.

Comment: …also, if you want `ItemHeight` to be displayed in the VS Properties window, decorate it with `System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, Yes I rebuilt it before adding to the form. Unfortunately didn't work.
Jimi - Yes, I can change the font size.
rfmodulator - Unfortunately I need a nuget package in the solution that only works for x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Visual Studio 2017 (2019?) *still* doesn't play nicely with 64-bit controls in the Toolbox. This is primarily because VS is a 32-bit application.

The normal solution is to build the project that contains your custom control(s) for the "Any CPU" platform. This might even mean creating a separate Class Library project to house them.

The quick and easy solution (subjective), is to add your custom control(s) to your `Form` in code and avoid the designer.

If changing `ItemHeight` is the *only* creative thing you want to do, I'll offer a workaround that uses the standard `CheckedListBox` control and reflection.

In your `Form` constructor, **after** the line `InitializeComponent();`, do the following:

```
var heightField = typeof(CheckedListBox).GetField(
    "scaledListItemBordersHeight", 
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
);

var addedHeight = 10; // Some appropriate value, greater than the field's default of 2

heightField.SetValue(clb, addedHeight); // Where "clb" is your CheckedListBox
```

This requires:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

This works because, internally, `ItemHeight` is a read-only property that returns `Font.Height + scaledListItemBordersHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated by OP's comment]
If you need inherit some class, here is step for you.

1. Add user control to your project
   Right click your project -> add -> User control. Visual studio will create 2 files.
   (UserControl.cs and UserControl.Designer.cs)
2. Basically when you create user control, it inherit from `UserControl`.
   So change it to `CheckedListBox`.
3. Add `: base()` at constructor as below.
4. Remove line to prevent compile error.
   `this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;`
   at `UserControl.Designer.cs`.
5. Add some properties, and if you set it `public` you can see it designtime as below picture. [image]

If parent class need to be initialized, child class should add `base()` in constructor of your class.
And basic idea for design time action from [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemheight?view=netframework-4.8)

```cs
//Change parent class UserControl --> CheckedListBox.
//public partial class MyListBox : UserControl  
public partial class MyListBox : CheckedListBox
{
    /*
        Add base() in your constructor.
    */
    public MyListBox() : base()
    {  
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Add some properties.
    private int _ItemHeightOffSet = 0;

    public int ItemHeightOffSet {
        get { return _ItemHeightOffSet; } 
        set { 
            this._ItemHeightOffSet = value;

            /*
               This will help you adjust height in design time.
               When 'DesignMode' is true  --> Control loaded at Visual Studio. : Design time.
               When 'DesignMode' is false --> Control loaded at debuging or running. : Run time.
            */
            if (DesignMode == true)
            {
                base.ItemHeight = value + ItemHeightOffSet;
                base.Refresh();
            }
        } 
    }

    public override int ItemHeight
    {
        get { 
            return base.ItemHeight + ItemHeightOffSet; 
        }
        set
        {
            base.ItemHeight = value + ItemHeightOffSet;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jornathan for the response. There are a few things a little over my head though. 1) Which constructor are you talking about to add base()? I haven't heard the term constructor before now. 2) InitializeComponent(); give me the error "Doesn't exist in the current context. 3) I'm also unfamiliar with the term DesignMode. Is that something I have to add to my main form or does this execute automatically, being a property of the checklist? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Hi, I update my answer, if you need further information, add comment again.